# Why wrap JavaScript in this "(function($){ ... JavaScript code ..})(jQuery);"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I use mvc5. Do not include jQuery in test.
_Layout.cshtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Test.cshtml:

```html
<script type="javascript/text">
  function myFunction() {
    alert("its is working");
  }
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

In result I have an error: ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

and the result code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction();">Click me</button> 
<script type='text/javascript' >
(function($){
    function myFunction() {
      alert("I am working");
    };
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read a lot about this error and have not founded the answer. Could you clarify, who wrap JavaScript code? Is there any flag to cancel it? Is there any other way to resolve the problem?

Comment: Inline functions are suppose to be in global scope to be accessed..Do not wrap function `definition` in `IIFE`

Comment: and inline functions are a horribly obsolete way of handling events, especially since you're already committed to using jQuery

Comment: That particular function is one of the ways to execute a `document.ready` event handler for jQuery, ensuring that the DOM is completely loaded before the code is executed.  You would typically do this where you need to reference DOM elements in your script, so this makes sure they exist before you do so.  To resolve the issue simply move `myFunction()` outside that anonymous function so it has global scope.

Comment: [Bind event handlers with JavaScript](http://api.jquery.com/on/); don't use instinsic event attributes (which depend on globals which are awful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something (probably MVC5) is wrapped your code for you, but with good reason.  Putting `onclick` handlers on elements pointing at a globally declared function is how JS was written in the '90s.

To resolve it, put an `id` attribute on your button and remove the inline event handler:

```
<button id="mybutton">
```

and then use jQuery to register the event handler:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function () {
  alert("I am working");
});
```

or, since you mentioned in later comments that you have a loop generating these elements, use a `class` and a `data-` attribute instead:

```
<button class="myclass" data-id="...">
```

with code:

```
$('.myclass').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    ...
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. In that case I have an error; ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined })(jQuery);

Comment: @Iva so you need to load `jQuery` with a `<script>` tag

Comment: I would like to use inline function because I add this peace of code on the server in loop. This problem looks very stupid for me. I think I missed something very simple.

Comment: @Alnitak he's asking how his function is being wrapped in `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);` since he didn't.

Comment: @pumpkinzzz looks like MVC5 did, then?   Either way, using inline event handlers is error prone and brittle.

Comment: If I load jQuery, you code works fine, but in line code (bad practice which I prefer for this situation) has an error: ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @Alnitak i agree, but is not what he's asking for :) i mean, what if he don't want to use jQuery at all?

Comment: Yes, because your `myFunction` is declared within the scope of another function, and is therefore not global.  Using inline event handlers will only give you a short term fix - you'll be far better off learning how to use proper event handlers, especially if you're using (since you mentioned a loop) multiple similar elements.

Comment: @pumpkinzzz I know, but I cannot in good conscience recommend any work around that'll avoid the wrapping and allow his inline event handlers to work.

Comment: @Alnitak sure it's a bad practice to use inline code, but I have no idea how many buttons will be added. If I follow your advice the logic will be very complicated.Maybe I have not got your idea, please clarify in that case.

Comment: @Iva it's perfectly possible to handle multiple buttons _extremely cleanly_ using jQuery, but that would be a different question altogether.

Comment: @Alnitak I agree with you. I have one more option in code, I send addition parameter - ID in this function. If I do not use inline code, I need to find all buttons by class (for example). After that I have to parse names to get the ID and .. Its very complicated. To save simplify - better to use bad practice.Please correct me, if I am not right.

Comment: @Iva no, it's trivial - `<button class="myButton" data-id="1">` - then `$('.myButton').on('click', function() { var id = $(this).data('id') })`

Comment: @Alnitak it's not about looking for a workaround here, is about to understand how is generated that code, that's the question. Your answer is a workaround to the question though

Comment: @Alnitak thank you a lot for the help. Its not exactly what I asked but this is one of the way to resolve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @pumpkinzzz and that's why I tagged this Community Wiki, so that the OP can learn the right way, even though it's not what he asked.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("its is working");
}
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

This will work. cheers